# convert sql query to linq

Tags: sql, linq

I have this SQL query :

```
select RoleID 
 from tblUserRole
 where UserID = 1
   and RoleID in 
       (Select ID from tblGreenRole 
        Where 
        IsFullAccess = 1)
```

How can I convert this query to linq?

Comment: Show us what **you've tried** so far - where are you stuck?

Comment: Simplified and made question more obvious.  Formatted code to make a little easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 var result = (from t1 in context.tblUserRole
 join t2 in context.tblGreenRole on t1.RoleID equals t2.ID
 where t1.UserID == 1 && t2.IsFullAccess == 1).ToList();
```

If `IsFullAccess` is of type bit then change to `&& t2.IsFullAccess == true` or just `&& t2.IsFullAccess`